# perl while loop iterates through a variable.

Tags: perl

This little snippet is  from the first chapter of the LWP perl oreilly book.
This line

```
$count++ while $catalog =~ m/Perl/gi;
```

perplexes me

I do not understand how the while statement iterates through the lines in the $catalog variable to find the matched, I don't even know how to explain what that line does in english much less perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict ;
use LWP::Simple ;
my $catalog = get("http://www.oreilly.com/catalog");
my $count = 0;
$count++ while $catalog =~ m/Perl/gi;
print "$count\n";
```

so I have tried writing it out long hand to no avail.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict ;
use LWP::Simple ;
my $catalog = get("http://www.oreilly.com/catalog");


open( my $fh_catalog ,"<" , $catalog) || die "cant open $!";
while (<$fh_catalog>) {
    print $_ ;
    sleep 1;
}
```

I even tried

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict ;
use LWP::Simple ;
my $catalog = get("http://www.oreilly.com/catalog");

while (<$catalog>) {
    print $_ ;
    sleep 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$catalog` contains the string `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUB[...][newline][newline]<html>[...]`.

Your first snippet fails because `$catalog` doesn't contain a file name.

Your second snippet fails because `$catalog` doesn't contain a file handle.

When a match operator with the `/g` modifier is used scalar context, it searches from where the last search left off.

The analog would be

```
use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );  # Support sleeping fractions of seconds.
$| = 1;  # Turn off STDOUT's output buffering.
for my $i (0..length($content)-1) {
   print(substr($content, $i, 1));
   sleep 0.1;
}
```

---

Let's use a simpler string as an example.

```
my $s = "a000a000a000";
++$count while $s =~ /a/g;
```

Here's what happens:

1. The match operator is executed. It finds the first `a`, sets `pos($s) = 1;`, and returns true.
2. The loop body is entered, and `$count` is incremented.
3. The match operator is executed. It behaves as if the string started as `pos($s)` (`1`), finds the second `a`, sets `pos($s) = 5;`, and returns true.
4. The loop body is entered, and `$count` is incremented.
5. The match operator is executed. It behaves as if the string started as `pos($s)` (`5`), finds the third `a`, sets `pos($s) = 9;`, and returns true.
6. The loop body is entered, and `$count` is incremented.
7. The match operator is executed. It behaves as if the string started as `pos($s)` (`9`), fails to find a match, clears `pos($s)`, and returns false. The loops exits.

Nothing changes if some of the characters of the string are newlines.

Comment: thank you Ikegami - I knew global meant search the whole document, but did not understand how it searched globally. watching the analog version print out is the coolest.